# Discord.py[voice] giving installation error

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6, discord.py, pythonista

I am trying to install discord.py with voice support into Pythonista on my iPad using StaSh. The problem is that when I enter the command `pip install discord.py[voice]` like it says to in the documentation, I get an error that says `Error: Failed to fetch package release urls`. Can anyone help me figure out what the issue is here? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this GitHUb issue](https://github.com/ywangd/stash/issues/309)?  It looks like that should already have been fixed though.  Are you using the latest version of StaSH?

Comment: Yes I have seen that GitHub issue. I checked my pip.py file and all of the mentions of https are there instead of http like they said in the issue. My error only occurs when I try to install discord.py[voice]. I have used it to install the basic discord.py module but I want the full voice support as well.

Comment: Can you install PyNaCl independently?  That's the dependency discord.py uses for voice problems, and it can be difficult to install on some systems.

Comment: I have tried that too. It works just fine until it gets to running setup.py. When it gets to that it just sits there and never completes the installation.

Comment: So I just realized that maybe my issue with installing PyNaCl was that I was running StaSh in python 3 instead of python 2. I tried running it in python 2 and instead of stopping at the setup file, it gave me this error.

Comment: Are you trying to install `discord.py` for Python 2?  That won't work.  `discord.py` requires the asynchronous programming frameworks introduced in Python 3.4

Comment: Oh. Ok. Never mind then. I tried it again in python 3 and it still stops at the setup.py file.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [discord.py repo on Github](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py#installing), the command may be different depending on your OS.

In Linux/macOS you should use the command with `"`:

```
pip install "discord.py[voice]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add quotemarks around "discord.py[VOICE]" and see if it works

Comment: The error isn't about PATH. It's about PyPI installation.

Comment: oops - sorry i misread - i'll edit it right now

Answer (score 0):

In discord.py docs, it says using this command:
`pip install -U discord.py[voice]`
try that.